# SharePoint Server 2010 installation fails due to dbwrap timeout error

Tags: installation

Installing SharePoint Server 2010 on a Windows 7 (x64) Ultimate machine. All required items have been installed. But the installation fails on `dbwrap.exe` time out that I find in the `setup.exe` file. in the setup file.
Here follows three XML fragments

```
Command Path="%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\SERVER14\Server Setup Controller\**dbwrap.exe**" Args="timeout=2950" ChainPosition="after" Execute="Install" Wait="3000000"/
Command Path="%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\SERVER14\Server Setup Controller\dbwrap.exe" Args="timeout=2950 InstallMode=Repair" ChainPosition="before" Execute="Repair" Wait="3000000"
Command Path="%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\SERVER14\Server Setup Controller\dbwrap.exe" Args="timeout=2950 InstallMode=Uninstall" ChainPosition="before" Execute="Uninstall" Wait="3000000"
```

I don't find this file on my machine anywhere. I don't find it in the Common Files|Microsoft Shared

Appreciate any help

Comment: Have you followed **all the instructions** at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx ?

Comment: Also this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadminprevious/thread/34fdc97a-d658-4fd1-93e6-9c039d5b4b55

Comment: moontear, Thanks. I have already seen the links you mentioned. There appears to be MSSQL$Sharepoint in the Registry and one of the program complaints if I try to configure is, that it does not start. Perhaps it is not there to start.

Comment: SQL SERVER Discovery Tool does not find any SQL Server 2008 .

Answer (score 0):

I did have a problem with `dbwrap.exe` during my installation of SharePoint Foundation 2010, but it was solved by changing the registry value:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\WSS\ServerRole`

from `SINGLESERVER` to `APPLICATION` and rerunning the setup.

[Source reference](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/efc5e72d-6d72-4d21-abad-6fdc60396b6e/installation-errors-in-sharepoint-2010)