# BDC Deployment to Foundation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, deployment, sharepoint-server, bdc

I was able to successfully develop and test a BDC model developed in visual studio 2010. It was developed on a server using SharePoint Server 2010. I tried deploying the solution to our SharePoint Foundation 2010 Farm and receive an error stating that Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.ClientExtensions cannot be found.

I installed the dll in GAC of all the web front end servers and the Microsoft.Office.Server dll. even after restarting the timer services and resetting IIS I still receive the same error. I even copied the DLL in the SharePoint ISAPI folder. I don't understand how to get this deployed. I found a workaround on the internet but the custom code download page returns a 404 so I can't implement the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 files you have to copy to ISAPI folder and 2 dll register to the GAC.

In order to cross off this problem, some files of SharePoint Server 2010 need to be copied, which can be found in the directory 14\ISAPI:

- microsoft.office.sharepoint.clientextensions.dll
- Microsoft.Office.Sharepoint.ClientExtensions.xml
- Microsoft.Office.Server.dll
- Microsoft.Office.Server.xml

Register the DLLs in the GAC to fix it, just copying them to the directory C:\Windows\assembly.

Reopen the Visual Studio 2010 and deploy your BDC Model Solution successfully!

http://www.sharepoint4developers.net/en-nz/post/add-solution-failed-to-load-receiver-assembly.aspx

other option is. you will need to write a Feature Event Receiver to enable the deployment of BDC models from within Visual Studio 2010

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2010/10/10/9989848.aspx

Comment: I ended up installing Search Server Express and it worked perfectly. I tried the above steps with no success.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, but couldn't install Search Server Express (won't install on Windows 7) nor could I install SharePoint 2010 (not Foundation) to copy the required DLLs.

```
OS: Windows 7 Professional  
VS: Visual Studio Professional 2013  
SP: SharePoint Foundation 2010
```

My steps to get this working:

1. Download Search Server Express
2. Extract: `SearchServerExpress_SP2_en-us.exe /extract:c:\downloads\SearchServerExpress_SP2_en-us`
3. In the Search Server Express extracted folder, browse to /Global/Shared/osrv.cab, extract "MICROSOFT.OFFICE.SERVER.DLL" and "MICROSOFT.OFFICE.SERVER.XML"
4. In the Search Server Express extracted folder, browse to /Global/Search/osrchwfe.cab, extract "MICROSOFT.OFFICE.SHAREPOINT.CLIENTEXTENSIONS.XML"
5. Download "microsoft.office.sharepoint.clientextensions.dll" from [github](https://github.com/SubPointSolutions/spmeta2/tree/master/SPMeta2/SPMeta2.Dependencies/SharePoint/SP2010%20-%2014.0.6029.1000/SSOM)
6. Open visual studio developer command prompt as administrator, cd to folder with the above DLLs, run `gacutil -i [file].dll` to add DLLs to GAC
7. Restart Visual Studio as administrator, build and deploy

Installed an another win7 machine and had to change `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\WSS\ServerRole` from `SINGLESERVER` to `APPLICATION` as per [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/79805/41872)

Comment: This was a life saver

Answer (score 1):

If you install Microsoft Search Server Express it will provide all the necessary assemblies required to deploy BDC models to SharePoint. I tried and tested this solution.